# Thread C segmentation fault a simple program

Tags: c, multithreading, segmentation-fault, pthreads

I need your help to find the problem in this code: it's the main function of my program that simulates a multiprocessor system. I use thread library to build the Ram entity and all CPUs. Compiling there aren't problems and most of the executions work well. But, sometime, I launch the exe and after one or two prints, there is a segmentation fault.

So, I try to find it using gdb (without any response) and valgrind. The only thing that Valgrind told to me is that there was only a possibly lost (this is the messagge:  272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 1 of 1).

Ps. I write #include for each library function.

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  if(argc!=3)
  syserr("Utilizzo: simulazione <numCpu> <ramDim>\n");

  pthread_t ram;
  ram_dim=atoi(argv[2]);

  int num_cpu=atoi(argv[1]);
  pthread_t cpu[num_cpu];

  command *cpu_info=(command *) malloc(sizeof(command)*num_cpu);
  request *buffer=(request *) malloc(sizeof(request));

  int curs, status;
  pthread_attr_t attr;

  pthread_attr_init(&attr);
  pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attr, PTHREAD_CREATE_JOINABLE);

  pthread_mutex_init(&ram_lock, NULL);
  vpthread_mutex_lock(&ram_lock);

  if((status=pthread_create(&ram, &attr, ram_job, (void *) buffer))!=0)
    syserr("Creazione thread Ram fallita.\n");

  pthread_mutex_init(&cpu_lock, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_init(&rw_lock, NULL);
  pthread_mutex_lock(&rw_lock);

  for(curs=0;curs<num_cpu;curs++)
  {
    cpu_info[curs].istr=buffer;
    cpu_info[curs].num_cpu=curs+1;

    if((status=pthread_create(&cpu[curs], &attr, cpu_job, (void *) &cpu_info[curs]))!=0)
        syserr("Creazione thread Cpu fallita.\n");
  }

  pthread_attr_destroy(&attr);

  for(curs=0;curs<num_cpu;curs++)
    pthread_join(cpu[curs], (void **) 0);

  free(buffer);
  free(cpu_info);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&rw_lock);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&cpu_lock);
  pthread_mutex_destroy(&ram_lock);

  return 0;
```

}

Comment: What makes you think the bug is in main and not in the thread functions?

Comment: Because Valgrind said to me that there is only a memory leak in main, exactly at this line:  if((status=pthread_create(&ram, &attr, ram_job, (void *) buffer))!=0)

Answer (score 0):

Join with that thread is missing. Add:

```
pthread_join(ram, 0);
```

Somewhere at the end before you destroy the resources used by that thread.

But that probably won't fix that crash because you need first to stop that thread gracefully somehow.

Answer (score 0):

Because if there's an error, syserr will return. If there's an error, it will do something close to "printf(...); exit(...);".

And you will never do the rest of the code, which is suppose to free all variables.

Use "strerror(errno)" instead ;)